# What does that mean $f(x) < f(\infty)$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is increasing for $x > 0$ such that $f(x) < f(\infty)$. What doest the last inequality mean? Does that mean $f(x)$ is bounded? As an example, let $f(x)=x$, does that mean $f(x) < f(\infty)$?

Comment: In which context are you encountering this? This is, at best, non-standard notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I'd read it is that $f(\infty)$ stands for the *extended* real number $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ (i.e. possibly $f(\infty)=\infty$) and that the condition is supposed to be $f(x)<f(\infty)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. In the case $f(\infty)=\infty$ the condition should add nothing. In the case $f(\infty)\in\Bbb R$, the condition should add the fact that $f(x)<f(\infty)$ for all $x\le 0$, and that $f$ is not eventually constant as $x\to\infty$.